# Modifying methods in helper class

Tags: c#

Recently I came across a question which I was not very sure about. The scenario is :

Say we have a helper class : H and a method in helper class M1(int a, int b, int c) accepts three parameters. There are three classes which make use of this method : C1, C2, C3.

Now, we need another class C4 which also uses method M1 and will pass four parameters instead of three.

So, how do we tackle this problem.

Do we need Extension methods.?

Comment: no,simply overload M1 in H?

Comment: If C4 needs to perform the same calculations as C1, C2 and C3, then simply add a optional param to M1 and handle the 4th param as needed. If C4 performs completely different actions create a new overload method `M1(int a, int b, int c, int d)`

Answer (score 2):

You can overload the `M1()` method using default parameter:

```
public static void M1(int a, int b, int c, int? d = null)
{
    // working with a, b, c

    if (d == null)
        return;

    var dValue = (int)d; // casting the nullable int to int to work with

    // use the d parameter
}
```

In C1, C2, C3 you will call:

```
H1(1, 2, 3);
```

in C4 you will call:

```
H1(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

*Note: the `int?` makes the input parameter `nullable`, so you can set it to `null`. This way you won't have to choose a number as default parameter (which could be passed intentionally as well).*

Comment: ... yeah that's an option, but now you can use H1 with 4 arguments in C1/C2/C3 as well. You don't always want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default argument, but that has the issue that C1, C2 and C3 also get the overload with 4 arguments and C4 will get the overload with 3 arguments. The way you stated your question, I'm guessing that doesn't make sense (especially the C4 with 3 arguments usually doesn't make sense in real-life designs).

The way forward is to introduce a protected member and forward the calls. Basically your code will look something like this:

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    protected void H1B(int a, int b, int c, int d) { ... }
}

public class BaseClassFor3 : BaseClass
{
    public void H1(int a, int b, int c) { H1B(a,b,c,0); } // forward call
}

public class C1 : BaseClassFor3 {} // etc
public class C2 : BaseClassFor3 {} // etc 
public class C3 : BaseClassFor3 {} // etc

public class C4 : BaseClass
{
    public void H1(int a, int b, int c, int d) { H1B(a,b,c,d); } // forward call
}
```

**Adding a nullable or a parameter**

Now here's a tricky question from @KAI: in what cases you you add a `int? d` or another overload? Here goes.

As a rule of thumb, **I always attempt to keep the functionality of a class independent of the functionality of other classes**. This basically means that if you have C4, the code in the base classes shouldn't check for a condition that is implied by a sub class (such as C4).

So let's say we would have had this:

```
public void H1(int a, int b, int c, int? d) //...
```

usually this implies that somewhere down the line we would get this code:

```
if (d.HasValue) 
{ 
    // handle something that's specific for C4
}
```

Because this breaks the independency idea, I would never go for that.

Now there are two options:

1. The H1 call implementations share the same name (because that's easy to understand when using the class), but otherwise have little with each other in common.
2. The H1 call implementation share a lot of the same code (apart from the name).

*As an example for (1)*: If you're familiar with f.ex. PDF applications, C1-C4 might actually be a vector operations on a 4x4 matrix. In such cases, some operations have 3 operands, and others have 4 operands. In the case where the operand is omitted, we usually implicitly mean `0`.

In this case, we add a common protected base class with an `int`, and implement it like above. Note that there's no `if` involved in the code of the base class; its functionality is isolated in the base class, like it should be.

In such a scenario, I would also use a `Nullable` -- but if you start thinking about it like this, you'll notice that nullables will be very, very rare.

*In scenario (2)* the answer is different. For example, let's assume that H1 inserts something in a database. It makes little sense to implement shared code twice or copy-paste it. It's much better to isolate the code, create a separate method and call it from the 3/4 parameter implementation. It'll probably look like this:

```
public void H1(int a, int b, int c, int d) 
{
    // NOTE: this is just an example, I'd normally use an OR mapper!

    // Construct query using a,b,c
    string baseQuery = ConstructQuery(a,b,c);
    baseQuery += " and d = " + d.ToString();

    // ...
    ExecuteSql(baseQuery);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this solution before I wrote my answer, but in the question he mentioned: **"Say we have a helper class: H"**. I think he meant a static helper class (maybe an instance), but not a base class. Actually, using the helper class inside your base classes would be the best solution (in the question's context), right?

Comment: It depends... for example, if he's using code generation, extension classes make a lot of sense. Still, in the normal case I'd simply use base classes instead of extension classes.

Comment: Thanks. An other question: wouldn't it be better to use two different parameter list (or a `nullable` parameter) instead of having the 4th as `0`? What if my method should work with every single `int`? I know it's just an example, but I'm asking it, since it looks like you have much more experience, and I'm curious.

Comment: @KAI That's a tricky one... let me whip up an update to my answer.